# Why does test -e fail on a file in a directory with only read permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, test

From what I understand about the read permission on directories, it allows listing of which files are in a directory and that's about it.

Given a directory with 0744 permissions, owned by `userA`:

```
[userA@localhost ~]$ mkdir -m 0744 /tmp/semi-secret
[userA@localhost ~]$ ls -ld /tmp/semi-secret/
drwxr--r--. 2 userA userA 6 Aug 29 10:15 /tmp/semi-secret/
[userA@localhost tmp]$ touch semi-secret/foobar.txt
[userA@localhost tmp]$ chmod 0600 semi-secret/foobar.txt
```

To `userB`, The existence of the file `foobar.txt` is apparent from the `ls` command.

```
[userB@localhost ~]$ ls -l /tmp/semi-secret/
ls: cannot access /tmp/semi-secret/foobar.txt: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? foobar.txt
```

But why does the `test -e` command exit with a non-zero status?!  Its only job is to confirm if a file exists or not, and directory permissions are supposed to allow that.

```
[userB@localhost ~]$ test -e /tmp/semi-secret/foobar.txt || echo "The file doesn't exist."
The file doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since even the `stat(2)` system call cannot work for any file in a directory that misses the `x` bit in the permissions, anything that is based on the `stat(2)` system call will fail in such a directory.

If your directory has the `r` bit set, you are indeed able to read the content of that directory using`readdir()`, but you cannot `stat` or `open` any file.

In contrary, a directory that has the `x` bit set, allows you to `stat(2)` or `open` files if you know the related file names but you cannot use `readdir()` to retrieve the content of the related directory.

`test -e` exits with a non-zero status in case that either the file does not exist (after symlink resolution, so that also applies to *existing* symlinks to *non-existing* or non-accessible files) or any error occurs while trying to `stat(2)` the related file.

Answer (score 3):

To complement @schily's fine answer, one way to check that a given directory for which you have read access but not necessarily *search* access, contains an entry by a given name is to read the content of that directory and look for that file name.

You can use shell globbing for that.

```
set -- /tmp/semi-secret/[f]oobar.txt
if [ "$1" = /tmp/semi-secret/foobar.txt ]; then
  echo exists
fi
```

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
if ()(($#)) /tmp/semi-secret/foobar.txt(N); then
  echo exists
fi
```

With `find` implementations that support `-maxdepth`:

```
if find /tmp/semi-secret -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name foobar.txt -print |
     grep -q '^'; then
  echo exists
fi
```

Except for the `zsh` solution, it's hard to adapt to arbitrary file names though.